# What is a sufficiently complex system?

Tags: complexity-theory, artificial-intelligence

I have been reading about the AI approaches, and I came across the [AI emergent approach](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/05/17/google_ai_hogwash/) that has the following definition:

**That is, the appearance of an entity with a sense of its own identity and agency within a sufficiently complex system.**

And I have got trouble understanding the meaning I have read the the paper [What is a complex system?](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/9044/4/LLWultimate.pdf) and the definition in this [site](http://www.scilogs.com/a_mad_hemorrhage/formal-definitions-and-complex-systems/), But I have still got trouble understanding the whole expression what does sufficiently mean exactly in this expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means "a system whose complexity is high enough to allow it to do [whatever thing we're talking about]."